# Automatically import resource after creation

Tags: terraform

I have some terraform VMware NSX-T/VRA code like this (gotten from official [github repo](https://github.com/vmware-samples/validated-solutions-for-cloud-foundation/blob/main/pca/docs/sample-project/4-configure-profiles.md))

```
resource "nsxt_policy_segment" "overlay_segment" {
  for_each            = {for segment in var.nsxt_segments : segment.name => segment}
  display_name        = each.value.name
  transport_zone_path = data.nsxt_policy_transport_zone.overlay_tz.path
  connectivity_path   = data.nsxt_policy_tier1_gateway.t1_gw.path
  subnet {
    cidr = each.value.cidr
  }
}


# Add network fabric settings for internal (non-IPAM) IP address management.

resource "vra_fabric_network_vsphere" "network0" {
  cidr                 = var.cidr_network0
  default_gateway      = var.default_gateway_network0
  domain               = var.domain
  dns_search_domains   = var.dns_search_domains
  dns_server_addresses = var.dns_server_addresses
}

resource "vra_fabric_network_vsphere" "network1" {
  cidr                 = var.cidr_network1
  default_gateway      = var.default_gateway_network1
  domain               = var.domain
  dns_search_domains   = var.dns_search_domains
  dns_server_addresses = var.dns_server_addresses
}
```

The `vra_fabric_network_vsphere` uses the id from the `nsxt_policy_segment`. However, the problem here comes from `terraform import vra_fabric_network_vsphere.network0 <id_of_created_segment>`. I would really like to when the segments are created, to have them imported automatically (since they will be used further down the plan) with something like:

```
import {
  to = vra_fabric_network_vsphere.network0
  id = nsxt_policy_segment.overlay_segment[0].id
}
```

But that has the issue of: `The import block "id" argument depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot plan to import this resource.`

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Well, for one, it seems you are using `for_each`, and I'm guessing the key in for each won't be the same as using the `count` meta-argument, where indexes are used.

Comment: That is a different problem that can be addressed fairly easily. Even if there is no for_each, this stays as an error.

Comment: The two different resources share the same id?

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

The `import` construct helps you to import a resource that ***exists already*** (identified by its `id`).

> The import ID must be known at plan time for planning to succeed. If the value of id is only known after apply, terraform plan will fail with an error.
>
> SOURCE: [Terraform Documentation on Import ID](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#import-id)

You can reference `nsxt_policy_segment` as follows, and Terraform will derive the dependencies and thus, the order to create the resources.

```
resource "vra_fabric_network_vsphere" "network0" {
  # Your resource reference on the next line
  some-argument        = nsxt_policy_segment.overlay_segment[0].id
  # ...
}
```

## TL;

You are inverting the flow with the `import` block.

Here's a working example:

```
import {
  id = "projects/${data.google_project.this.number}/locations/${local.region}/connections/${local.project}"
  to = google_cloudbuildv2_connection.web
}
```

The next issue is you are trying to import a`nsxt_policy_segment` resource type into a `vra_fabric_network_vsphere`'s. I must believe it is a mistake on your part (unless you tell me VMWare uses the same ID for both... I'm not familiar with VMWare).

> ```
> import {
>   to = vra_fabric_network_vsphere.network0
>   id = nsxt_policy_segment.overlay_segment[0].id
> }
> ```

Furthermore... Looking [that module documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/vmware/vra/latest/docs/resources/vra_fabric_network_vsphere#import), it reads that usage to import `vra_fabric_network_vsphere` is as:

```bash
terraform import \
  fabric_network_vsphere.new_fabric_network_vsphere \ # the resource address
  05956583-6488-4e7d-84c9-92a7b7219a15                # the resource ID
```

If your `vra_fabric_network_vsphere` exists on the VMWare infrastructure already with an ID of `potato-network`, you can import it with the following:

```
import {
  id = "potato-network"
  to = vra_fabric_network_vsphere.network0
}
```

If it doesn't exist yet, then `terraform apply` will create it and if `some-argument` needs to reference network value...

```
resource "vra_fabric_network_vsphere" "network0" {
  # Your resource reference on the next line
  some-argument        = nsxt_policy_segment.overlay_segment[0].id
  cidr                 = var.cidr_network0
  default_gateway      = var.default_gateway_network0
  domain               = var.domain
  dns_search_domains   = var.dns_search_domains
  dns_server_addresses = var.dns_server_addresses
}
```

By referencing `nsxt_policy_segment` like this, Terraform will understand that `nsxt_policy_segment` must be created before `vra_fabric_network_vsphere`. And you do not need `import` either. Your state will reflect it correctly.

Comment: The problem occurs from this: I add ```nsxt_policy_segment```: in NSX-T. Since the nsx-t resource is referenced in vRA (via cloud account), the creation of those segments **automatically** (not terraform) create a resource of type  ```vra_fabric_network_vsphere``` and it needs to be imported. The ```some-argument``` solution here does not address the issue, as this instructs terraform to **create** the resource, not import it, which will give us the error described in the question

Comment: Can't it be queried as `data`? (I just checked the doc. No go.) Then that can be a two-step operation. First `terraform apply`, with only `resource "nsxt_policy_segment" [...]`. Then `apply` again with `import` and `resource "vra_fabric_network_vsphere" "network0"`

Comment: Yeah, that's my current work-around, however I do see this as getting to be a problem for larger infras.